# CSS3 boxshadow on top of all other elements?

Tags: html, css

I have a page setup as follows

```
<div class="Header"> Header content </div>

<div class="Content"> Main Body Content </div>
```

Now in the CSS for the header class, i'm putting

```css
.Header {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #000;
}
```

This box-shadow however gets covered up by the Content div.  Is there a way to have the shadow from this div on top of all other divs, without going the absolute positioning route?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You probably want to stick it on a higher z-index. try this:

```
.Header {
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;
}
```

Comment: No need to use z-index: 999 unles .Content has z-index:998 though. Probably, if .Content is not positioned (has no position:relative), it would be enough to have z-index:1 for this particular case

Comment: I'm using bootstrap - I had to use `z-index: 9` to get it to cover up my sidebar nav.